# Mostrar progreso webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Tengo una aplicacion en webforms en la cual al hacer clic sobre un asp button empieza a correr un procedimiento en el codebehind el procedimiento toma bastante tiempo e incluye un bucle for manejado por un contador de tipo int

Existe algun metodo para mostrar el valor de ese contador en la pagina mientras se esta ejecutando el bucle?

Probe con un ajax timer y un panel update con un label pero no funciona

Comment: como estas realizando ese click del boton? digo e un boton de asp.net o es un boton html que invoca al servidor mediente ajax de jquery

Comment: @LeandroTuttini un boton asp.net

Answer (score -1):

La forma de enviar acciones al cliente, o sea al browser, es por medio de la tecnica de `Push Server` la cual se implementa por medio de `SignalR`

[Introducción a SignalR](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr)

con este podrias tener un socket de comunicacion abierto entre el browser y el servidor para que este ultimo pueda enviar acciones

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero esto solo funciona si el browser no realizo un postbak de un evento, por eso seria bueno utilices una llamada `ajax` por medio de `jquery` aun webmethod, asi la pagina se no actualizara y el socket se mantendra activo para enviar acciones desde el servidor

[Call ASP.Net Page Method using jQuery AJAX Example](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx)

algo como lo que se describe en el articulo

Comment: porque un voto negativo? diganme en que me equivoco, le estoy planteando la tecnica para enviar mensajes desde el servidor al browser, en que me equivoque?

Comment: El voto negativo no fue mio, no he tenido tiempo de revisar la respuesta planteada, si es correcta la marcare...

Comment: no digo que votaras negativo a quien te haya querido ayudar, eso es raro, por lo general es algun revisor del foro quien realiza estas votaciones, pero estaria bueno que justifiquen asi se puede mejorar lo que vio incorrecto, asi se aprender, porque votar por votar no aporta mucho

Comment: no fue util la respuesta? porque sino elimino la respuesta ya que ademas la votaron negativo

Comment: No he tenido tiempo de revisarla